# Calling Lapack DLL from gfortran

Tags: r, windows, fortran, gfortran, lapack

I have installed R on Windows, which creates a file C:\programs\R\R-3.5.2\modules\x64\lapack.dll . The Fortran compiler used to build R is gfortran. How can I call Lapack routines from gfortran? I tried

gfortran C:\programs\R\R-3.5.2\modules\x64\lapack.dll xlin.f

where xlin.f is the [driver](http://physics.oregonstate.edu/~landaur/nacphy/lapack/codes/linear-f.html) and get the error message

C:...\ccwsB76i.o:xlin.f:(.text+0x120): undefined reference to `sgesv_'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check using the [gendef](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/gendef/) program (available as part of MinGW-w64 installations) what functions/subroutines a DLL contains. Apparently "modules\x64\lapack.dll" in the installation of *R for Windows* is not the library that you want. The correct one is "bin\x64\Rlapack.dll"!

But this is not the end of the story. At least in case of installation of R 3.6.1, that library contains only double precision variants of the LAPACK routines. So, I needed to transform your program to use `REAL*8` and `DGESV`. But then this worked:

```
> set "PATH=C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1\bin\x64;%PATH%"
> set "PATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;%PATH%"
> gfortran xlin.f "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1\bin\x64\Rlapack.dll"
> a.exe
   1.0000000597179521
   1.0000000618499254
   1.0000000465843075
```

which I was able to reproduce in Linux with the default LAPACK library.

Comment: Thanks -- works for me. An alternative to setting adding C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1\bin\x64 to the path is to copy the DLL's there to the current working directory.